# Need Drag and drop div

Tags: jquery, css

I have set of divs. I need to re-arrange div on the browser which is drag and drop function. suppose I want `add_block_2` div is top, drag that div and place it top. automatically first one is down.

Help me the code.

```
    <div class="add_block_1"> Some content </div>
    <div class="add_block_2"> Some content </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be achieved by using jQueryUI's [droppable interface](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) and after you got your position you can modify the DOM with jQuery's [DOM Insertion](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/) functions.